# Sorting an array that in the sorted array there are 3 differences between every adjacent elements

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures

Im having a trouble with this sorting question.
Describe an algorithm that sort an array with the conditions:

1.In the sorted array there are 3 possible differences (k1,k2,k3 all natural numbers) between every adjacent elements.

2.In the sorted array there are 3 possible differences (k1,k2=2k1,k3=3k1 all rational numbers) between every adjacent elements.

I was able to find the differences in both questions in a linear time O(n) but im stuck on O(nlogn) in the sotring part.

Trying maybe to an O(n) time or maybe O(nloglogn) by maybe refer to k1,k2,k3 as a really small numbers and use counting sort.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean my differences? Please clarify your question. If you managed to get down to O(nlogn) what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I mean that sorted array 1 can be 1,3,4,8,10 when k1=4 ,k2=1 k3=2. and sorted array 2 can be 2,8,16,96,192 when k1=2 k2 =4 k3=6 for exemple. im trying to maybe get an O(n) time or maybe O(nloglogn) by maybe refer to k1,k2,k3 as a really small numbers and you counting sort.

Comment: For Q1, k1, k2, k3 are unrelated ?

Comment: Yes in Q1 you cant assume anything about them, only that they are Naturals numbers.

Comment: Are they known in advance ?

Comment: No, but i have an algorithm to find them in O(n) so thats not the problem.